# How to properly validate SAML user is enabled or not in amazon cognito?

Tags: authentication, saml, amazon-cognito

I am using Cognito Users and SAML Users in my application.

**I want to understand how can i properly validate that my SAML User is revoked before login?**

For Cognit User, Amazon is calling [Login Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/login-endpoint.html) which is giving 401 response and we are directly seeing message 'User is disabled'

But how can i validate this while login with my SAML Idp?

I am getting '**invalid_grant**' while calling token endpoint for SAML user which is revoked.

(Can i use Pre authentication trigger? If yes, than how?)